# Are there LEGO sets unique to the UK/Europe?

Tags: sets, shopping

I'm going on vacation to the UK and am looking to pick up some sets for 2 collectors (if they have them).  It's a surprise gift so I don't want to ask them about it.

I am wondering if there are sets exclusively sold in the UK or Europe that are not easy to find in the US?

Comment: LEGO used to give away promotional polybags for free with the Daily Mail tabloid but [severed their ties last year](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-37962425) because of the newspapers reputation. The Sun (another tabloid) also ran similar promotions but I haven't seen anything recently. Whether or not LEGO has/had a similar promotion in the USA with the same sets, I don't know.

Comment: The [London Bus (40220)](http://brickset.com/sets/40220-1/London-Bus) was given away with qualifying purchases of ($75) or more in the U.S. and Canada. It's currently available in LEGO Stores in the UK (Although I'm not 100% sure if it's sold outside UK/Europe, it would make a wonderful souvenir and would potentially be quite collectable!)

Comment: It's not available in the UK, but if you're looking for exclusives, look on BL or take a plane to Billund and grab a 4000016 ;)

Answer (score 1):

I completely agree with what Gareth said above. There have been several sets sold exclusively in the Uk and Europe throughout Lego's production history. However, if what you are asking is recent or more unique/exciting ones, then I can think of a couple off the top of my head.

Lego BR toy minifigure sold(if I remember correctly) in [BR stores](http://top-toy.com/brpage/) in the UK:
[Brickset BR toy](https://brickset.com/sets/5001121-1/BR-LEGO-Minifigure)

Team GB series sold in UK and maybe Europe:
[Brickset GB team](https://brickset.com/sets/theme-Collectable-Minifigures/prices/subtheme-Team-GB)

DFB German football team sold exclusively throughout Europe(possibly only in Germany):
[Brickset DFB series](https://brickset.com/sets/71014-17/LEGO-Minifigures-DFB-Series-Complete)

London bus given at store opening in London:
[Brickset London Bus](https://brickset.com/sets/3300006-1/London-Bus)

Royal Guard buildable figure exclusive at Leicester Square store:
[Brickset Royal Guard](https://brickset.com/sets/3850033-1/Guardsman)

I know the 2 Lego CLub Max minifigures is exclusive, but I dunno if it was only sold in UK/Europe:
[Lime Green Max](https://brickset.com/minifigs/gen070/lego-club-lime-max) and [Regular Max](https://brickset.com/minifigs/gen029/lego-club-max)

The lego House minifigure/ set was sold in Billund stores:
[Lego House set](https://brickset.com/sets/containing-minifig-gen054)

The Legoland train is exlusive to Florida and Denmark:
[Legoland train](https://brickset.com/sets/4000014-1/The-LEGOLAND-Train)

The 2 Nesquik bunny sets were available in Germany, New Zealand, and Australia(who doesn't like chocolate milk?):
[Nesquik](https://brickset.com/sets/containing-minifig-gen003)

British exclusive minifigure Lester(not Chester, if you saw my edits):
[Lester minifigure](https://brickset.com/article/24402/lester-minifigure-here-s-how-to-get-one) However, it's been a while, so I don't think you can still get this from the scratch ticket.

Oh, alright, you caught me. I used Brickset. Sorry for the long post. This is about all that I could find/think of. Some of the entries that I found, I wasn't sure of, so I didn't post them. 
Please note that the places where they are sold are based only on my memory.

Comment: It should be noted that some of these are positively ancient and you're unlikely to find them in stores.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest having a look on the Lego website and changing your region to compare what you get in different places.

I know that neither of these probably qualify as "unique" but in the past I've come across sets that have been discontinued/launched in one region before another. For example, the Maersk Sealand was available in the Far East after it'd been discontinued in Europe. The other difference you'll see is with "customisations" - namely the stickers. For example, the Football Team bus 3404/5/6 was sold in different colours and with different stickers in different regions - I know I have one with England stickers and one with USA stickers on.